# how to toubleshoot nagios check_nrpe issues?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe

Steps done:

**On Nagios Server (CentOS 7)**

```
yum install nagios nagios-plugins-all
```

**On Target (CentOS 7)**

```
yum install nrpe nagios-plugins-all
```

modified `nrpe.cfg` and added master IP to `allowed_hosts`

```
systemctl enable nrpe && systemctl start nrpe
```

Now I'm trying to add a service check with check_nrpe
so I defined host, contact, contactgroup then check_nrpe command

```
nano /etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg

define command{
    command_name check_nrpe
    command_line $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

then added services for the nrpe check

```
nano /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg

define service {
        use                             basic-new-service
        name                            check-load-service
        normal_check_interval           3
        retry_check_interval            1
        notification_interval       30
        notification_options            w,c,r,u
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_load
        register                        0
        }

define service {
        use                             check-load-service
        service_description             SYS_HostLoad
        contact_groups                  Audit
    host_name                   TGT
        }
```

nagios service started successfully

```
systemctl enable nagios && systemctl start nagios
```

I can verify check_nrpe returns Ok status directly from CLI

```
# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H TGT -c check_load
OK - load average per CPU: 0.00, 0.00, 0.01|load1=0.000;0.150;0.300;0; load5=0.002;0.100;0.250;0; load15=0.008;0.050;0.200;0;
```

but in dashboard check_nrpe check is unable to succeed, due to permissions. (which I had already set as `nagios:nagios` for both `/etc/nagios` and `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins`)
it's showing this error on dashboard against this check

`(Return code of 13 for service 'SYS_HostLoad' on host 'TGT' was out of bounds)`

Comment: Testing the plugin as root is not very useful as the plugin will very likely *not* be executed by root when Nagios attempts to run it. `su` to the nagios user (or whichever user runs the plugin) and see if it works then. If it does not, fix it :) could be a permissions thing you overlooked

Comment: If you are able to run `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H TGT -c check_load` from the Nagios server successfully, there are NO client side NRPE issues. What happens if you define the service check directly (that is, without using the `check-load-service` and `basic-new-service` templates?